# Update a table sales with values from table products with WHERE clause in both Update and select query

Tags: php, sql

My aim is to get values from table products to table sales where sales.Product= products.Productname. This works well. with the code below .

```
UPDATE sales
SET Amount=(SELECT  Selling_Price FROM  products WHERE sales.Product= products.Productname);
        ;
```

My challenge now is how to update only where  sales.Amount= 0. While running this code. I want Column Amount with values ' != 0 ignored .

Answer (score 0):

> [...] how to update only where `sales.Amount= 0`. I want column `Amount` with values != 0 ignored .

Just add a `where` clause:

```
UPDATE sales
SET Amount = (SELECT Selling_Price FROM products WHERE sales.Product = products.Productname)
WHERE Amount <> 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to update rows where `amount = 0`, then you would add `where` clause to the `update`:

```
UPDATE sales
    SET Amount = (SELECT p.Selling_Price
                  FROM products p
                  WHERE sales.Product = p.Productname
                 )
    WHERE Amount = 0;
```

If `Amount` could be `NULL` and you want those rows updated as well, you would as `OR Amount IS NULL`.